# Mysql algorithmic (TREE) PLSQL / SQL

Tags: mysql, plsql, tree, hierarchical

I seek the solution for SQL browse my " SQL tree." I found several topics but I can not fit my problem.

Here is my example:

I have several element A ( ID = 1 ), B ( ID = 2 ), C ( ID = 3 ), D ( ID = 4 ), E ( ID = 5 ), F ( ID = 6 ), G ( ID = 7)

corresponding tree

```
------------- A ---------
|             |           |
B             C           D
|
E
------
|    |
F    G
```

I want to receive all ID descend from A ( 1,2,3,4 .. so ) but also to all the IDs from only E (5,6,7 )

I tested several recursive means, without success.

Note that I do not know the leaves which I want to achieve , so I have to necessarily go, the father to the son .

---

**My tables :**

**'alim'** :  all letters (Here letters for ex) with an ID

*Exemple :*

```
id  |  letters 
__________________
1   | A
2   | B
...
```

**'sous_categ'** : which contains the id of the id of A and son

*Exemple :*

```
id  |  id_sc_categ
__________________
1   | 2
1   | 3
1   | 4
```

---

*Links found : http://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/
http://sqlpro.developpez.com/cours/arborescence/*

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found the solution Mysql , so I treated the language used queries ( Php )